# Implicit partial derivative of a spherical cap

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

Consider a spherical cap, for which the base radius is $a$ and the height is $h$. Then, the surface area and volume is (these equations can be found on [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCap.html))

$A(a,h) = \pi(a^2 +h^2)$,

$V(a,h) = \frac{\pi h}{6}(3a^2 +h^2)$.

Taking the partial differential with respect to $a,h$ would give

$dA = 2\pi a \ da + 2\pi h \ dh$

$dV = \pi ha \ da + \frac{\pi}{2}(a^2+h^2) \ dh$.

My question is: how would one  evaluate $dA/dV$ when both $A$ and $V$ are described by more than one variable? For a sphere or a hemisphere, one can use the chain rule

$\frac{dA}{dV} = \frac{dA/dr}{dV/dr}$

as both $A$ and $V$ can be written as a function of $r \equiv 2h/(a^2+h^2)$, and one could easily find $dA/dV = 2/r$.

Answer (score 0):

You could write both $a$ and $h$ as functions of a single parameter $t$, and replace $da$ and $dh$ with $\frac{da}{dt}$ and $\frac{dh}{dt}$.  Then you're effectively saying that $a$ and $h$, both being dependent on $t$, are not independent as they are in $V(a, h)$ and $A(a, h)$. But this is okay as finding the total derivative implicitly assumes such a dependence.

Alternatively, you can explicitly write $h$ as a function of $a$ or vice versa.

Comment: Hi Vinay, thanks for your reply. However, I don't agree with either of the methods you mentioned. A spherical cap can be described by two parameters only - $(r,\theta)$ or $(a,h)$. In fact, since $a$ and $h$ are orthogonal, there's no way to describe both separately in terms of a single parameter $t$. Moreover, the other method you suggested, to write $h$ as $a$, would require the introduction of a second parameter.